# LDAPJS authentication and search

Tags: node.js, ldapjs

```
ldapsearch -h myserver.123.com -b 'dc=123,dc=com' -x uid=myid
```

This command works for me. Gets what I want. But I try hard to implement this functionality to  node.js

I try this example: I think that myserver.123.com doesn't need authentication. 
I don't know also how myserver.123.com is configured. What is important, the command above somehow works.

```
var password = '';
var username = 'myid';

var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var tlsOptions = {
    host: 'myid',
    port: '389'
};
var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'myserver.123.com',
    tlsOptions: tlsOptions
});

client.bind(username, password, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error occurred while binding');
    } else {
        var base = 'cn=user,dc=123,dc=com';
        var search_options = {
            scope: 'sub',
            filter: '(&(objectClass=*)(CN=' + username + '))',
            attrs: 'memberOf'
        };
        client.search(base, search_options, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error occurred while ldap search');
            } else {
                res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                    console.log('Entry', JSON.stringify(entry.object));
                });
                res.on('searchReference', function (referral) {
                    console.log('Referral', referral);
                });
                res.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Error is', err);
                });
                res.on('end', function (result) {
                    console.log('Result is', result);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am new in this technology. And I really don't know how make it works.

and this is my problem: "Error occurred while binding"
I dont know how to bind to this server. I dont have any documentation. So yeah here is problem. I have my command above and now I improvises.

Comment: Without an error there's nothing we can do to help you figure this out. Please add more information.

Comment: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` means that it can't find `myserver.123.com`. Make sure it's online and that you're using a _real_ LDAP server.

Comment: What happens when you issue `ping myserver.123.com` from your CLI?

Comment: yeah, you are right, I pasted my previous error. Sorry for that.
 Error occurred while binding - this is my currend problem. Becouse I dont know how to bind server which doesnt need authentication

Comment: When I had dalated binding section I got an error: Error is { NoSuchObjectError: NoSuchObjectError
    at messageCallback......
Error: read ECONNRESET

Answer (score -1):

here is a solution:

[[ldapjs authentification (user login setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255389/ldapjs-authentification-user-login-setup][1])