# Authorization in a NodeJS Express REST server

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization, passport.js

I am building a `REST` server in `nodejs` using `express`.

I would like to allow certain users to perform certain calls.
i.e. have an admin who can edit other users and see reports, where a user can only perform simple actions.

I was trying to use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) and [passport-ldapauth](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth), and also I would like to perform different queries for authentication (check credentials) and authorization (check if the user is part of a group).

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Allow self signed certificates
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
var OPTS = {
  server: {
    url: 'ldaps://...',
    bindDN: 'cn=Manager,dc=com',
    bindCredentials: 'secret',
    searchBase: 'ou=people,dc=com',
    searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})',
    tlsOptions: {
      ca: [fs.readFileSync('/path/to/certificate.crt')]
    }
  },
  handleErrorsAsFailures: true,
  failureErrorCallback: (err) => console.log(err)
};

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));
passport.use('test', new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!user) return res.status(401).send(info);

      res.json(user);
      // req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      //   if (err)
      //     console.error(err);
      //   if (err) return next(err);
      //   return res.json(user);
      // })
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Comment: what about jwt. Tried that yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `passport-ldapauth` strategy does not allow you to perform any additional checks or queries as far as I know from reading over the documentation. The strategy and Passport in general is aimed at making the login/authentication process seamless and easy as possible. So any additional constraints will need to be handled on your own.

With that said, `passport-ldapauth` utilizes [ldapauth-fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapauth-fork) underneath which in turn uses [ldapjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapjs). You can try to utilize `ldapjs` as shown [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-use-ldap-authentication-authorization-node.js-bluemix-application/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255389/ldapjs-authentification-user-login-setup), but I think the easiest solution would be to use `ldapauth-fork` directly.

We first need to set up `ldapauth-fork`, so we'll use the following example `app/ldap/index.js`:

```
const LdapAuth = require('ldapauth-fork')

const ldap = new LdapAuth({
  url: 'ldaps://...',
  bindDN: 'cn=Manager,dc=com',
  bindCredentials: 'secret',
  searchBase: 'ou=people,dc=com',
  searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})',
  tlsOptions: {
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('/path/to/certificate.crt')]
})

ldap.on('error', (err) => { throw err })

module.exports = ldap
```

Our example `app/controllers/auth.js` could look something like this:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const ldap = require('../ldap')
const { User } = require('../database/models') // mongoose model
const Promise = require('bluebird')

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body

  if (!username || !password) {
    res.status(400
    res.json({ error: 'Missing username or password.' })
    return
  }

  // ldapauth-fork doesn't support Promises.
  // You can try to promisfy it, but I prefer this.
  // I've named it `profile`, but you can name it whatever you want.
  const profile = await Promise.fromCallback(cb => ldap.authenticate(username, password, cb))

  // Since this is a REST API, we need to send back a token.
  // For this example, we're creating it by hand.
  const token = jwt.sign({ user: profile }, 'secret', {})

  // Use epoch time from the token instead of generating it ourselves.
  const { exp } = jwt.verify(token, 'secret')

  // Finally send the token.
  // By convention, the keys are snake case.
  res.json({
    access_token: token,
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    expires_in: exp,
    user: profile
  })
}
```

Now that we have our token created, we need a way to verify that token. To do that we need to write our own [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html). So for example `app/middleware/valid-token.js`:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

exports.needsAdminAccess = (req, res, next) => {
  // This token should have already been validated by the `requiresToken` middleware
  let token = req.header('authorization').split(' ')[1]
  token = jwt.verify(token, 'secret')

  // Let's check if they are in the admin group
  // Remember that we set the user/profile value in the controller.
  if (!token.user.dn.includes('ou=ADMIN')) {
    next(new Error('You must be an admin to access this route.'))
    return
  }

  // Any additional checks would go here.
  // ...

  // If everything is fine then call next to let the request continue.
  next()
}

exports.requiresToken = (req, res, next) => {
  // Assuming the token is in the header as Authorization: Bearer token
  let token = req.header('authorization').split(' ')[1]

  // Make sure our secret key matches
  token = jwt.verify(token, 'secret')

  // Additional checks of the token should be done here as well.
  // ...

  // Don't forget to call next if all is good
  next()
}
```

Finally we use the middleware wherever you define your routes, for example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { requiresToken, needsAdminAccess } = require('./middleware/valid-token')

// This route needs a valid token, but not admin rights
app.get('/user', requiresToken, (req, res) => { })

// This route needs a valid token AND admin rights
app.get('/admin', requiresToken, needsAdminAccess, (req, res) => { })
```

I wrote everything from scratch to hopefully paint a clear picture on how everything works. You can use [other](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) packages to validate the token for you, but we need to do verify specific things so we write our own.

Comment: looks good, but I am still unclear on how to add the authorization to specific calls. let's say that I have a `/admin` path and a `/user` path, and I want only admins to be able to access the first path, and any authenticated user to access the second path, how can I do that?